# iPhone - MPMusicPlayerController - Is there any limit on number of songs to select

Tags: iphone, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediapickercontroller

I created my own music player that runs on iPhone using the class `MPMusicPlayerController`.
I'm using the class `MPMediaPickerController` to select the songs and add to my player. 
I've around 900 songs in my iPhone. When I'm adding songs by selecting "Add All Songs" from `MpMediaPickerController`, the app is crashing.

Can some one tell me whether is there any solution to stop this crash?

Or is there any limit on number of songs selection that I've to impose so that app won't crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no limit on selection of songs.